# RSpec not seeing changes to ActiveRecord object with `change(object, :message)` syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I have three models:

- `User`
- `Company`
- `Commitment`

`Commitment` is a HABTM join table for `Users` and `Companies` (*i.e.,* when a `User` joins a `Company`, it creates a new `Commitment`). It also has a few extra columns/attributes:

- `admin` (does the user have admin privileges for this company?)
- `confirmed_by_admin` (has a company admin confirmed this user's request to join the company?)
- `confirmed_by_member` (has the user himself confirmed an invitation to join the company?)

I've also defined a convenience method to quickly determine if a commitment is fully confirmed:

```
class Commitment < ApplicationRecord
  def confirmed?
    confirmed_by_admin? && confirmed_by_member?
  end
end
```

Now I'm writing a request spec, but for some reason, the `change` matcher only works with one of its two syntaxes:

```
let :carol   { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let :company { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }

it 'confirms invitation to join company' do
  # Initialize unconfirmed commitment
  FactoryGirl.create(:commitment, user: carol,
                                  company: company,
                                  confirmed_by_admin: true)

  expect do
    patch commitment_path(carol.commitments.first),
          params: { commitment: { confirmed_by_member: true } }

  # for the following syntaxes, ------------------------------------------------
  # this works:
  end.to change { carol.commitments.first.confirmed?) }.from(false).to(true)
  # and this fails:
  end.to change(carol.commitments.first, :confirmed?).from(false).to(true)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end
```

It appears that `carol.commitments.first` isn't being reloaded when RSpec tests for the change — I get the following test output:

```
Failure/Error:
  expect do
    patch commitment_path(carol.commitments.first),
          params: { commitment: { confirmed_by_member: true } }
  end.to change(Commitment.find_by(user: carol, company: company), :confirmed?).from(false).to(true)

  expected #confirmed? to have changed from false to true, but did not change
# ./spec/requests/commitments_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What gives? Clearly I can just stick to the curly-brace / block syntax, but I'd like to understand why one works and not the other.

Comment: My conclusion: 

While this call may not realize object changes:
.to change(model, :attribute).from(false).to(true)

The block version with manual reload works:
.to change { model.reload.attribute ) }.from(false).to(true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon inspecting [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher) and trying out myself a new rails project replicating your scenarios, and also failing, I **believe** that the reason why it was failing is because

- the "block" form of `.change` is ran twice ("before" and "after" the `expect` block), whatever is inside of that block:

  `.change{ carol.commitments.first.confirmed? }`
- while the "method" form of `.change` is ran once for the first argument: `carol.commitments.first`, but ran twice for the second argument `:confirmed?`. However, the problem with this is that the the `carol.commitments.first` at this point inside the spec file does not share the same memory space as that object that has been actually updated in your `commitments_controller#update` (most likely that object is named `@commitment`). Although they are the same `Commitment` record, they are separate instances, and the attribute-values of the other do not automatically changes when the another one changed.

Consider the following which demonstrates a scenario in which this "method" form works:

```
it 'sometest' do
  commitment = FactoryGirl.create(:commitment, user: carol,
                                  company: company,
                                  confirmed_by_admin: true)
  expect do
    # this commitment object is exactly the same object passed in the `change` below
    commitment.confirmed_by_member = true
  end.to change(commitment, :confirmed?).from(false).to(true)
end
```

*Disclaimer: This is unverified, but because it was too complex for me write as a comment (with all the sample test code), I wrote it here as an answer. Should anyone know any better, please do let me know.*

Comment: Yep, I think that's it.

Comment: This appears to be the most likely explanation — that the `change` matcher doesn't reload the ActiveRecord object passed to it after the `expect` block is completed. I'm gonna file an issue on GitHub just to double-check, but I'm prepared to mark this solved unless someone else has more verifiable insight.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's good to know you folks also thought the same :)

Comment: @RyanLue: that issue will likely be rejected. RSpec doesn't know or care that you pass it an activerecord object. It can be any object.

Comment: But perhaps rspec-rails ought to?

Comment: @RyanLue: no. All rspec-rails does is install some hooks/generators and the like. It does not alter rspec behaviour.