# Rspec change Matcher only working with Block Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

```
it { expect { subject }.to change(tt.child_task_transactions.reload, :size).by 1 }
```

The above test doesn't pass with the message:

`` expected `TaskTransaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy#size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0 ``

However:

```
      it do
        subject
        expect(tt.child_task_transactions.reload.size).to eq 1
      end
```

passes correctly. And also:

```
it { expect { subject }.to change { tt.child_task_transactions.reload.size }.by 1 }
```

And this test passes, too.

Am I missing something here? I though the syntaxes are interchangeable [According to the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher).

I'm using
rspec 3.10.0,
Rails 6.1.4.1 and
Ruby 2.7.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RSpec not seeing changes to ActiveRecord object with \`change(object, :message)\` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274875/rspec-not-seeing-changes-to-activerecord-object-with-changeobject-message)

Comment: Does your experience change when using `count` instead of `size`?

Comment: @JakeWorth No, it will not. As technically described on duplicate mentioned above.

Comment: @BhavikParmar as far as I understand the the other example don't use reload, but I do and that is what puzzles me.